# How repeat modelos for a specific marca in this example?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, scopes

I want to repeat **just** of chevrolet modelos for example. this is my code

```
<body ng-controller="marcasController">
  <ul ng-repeat="marca in marcas">
    <li ng-repeat="tipo in marca.modelo">{{tipo.nombre}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>

var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('marcasController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.marcas =[

    {
      "nombre": "Chevrolet",
      "image": "images/aveo.jpg",
      "modelo": [
        {"nombre":"aveo", "color":"black"},
        {"nombre":"corsa", "color":"yellow"}
        ],
      "tab": "aveo"
    },
    {
      "nombre": "Renault",
      "image": "images/aveo.jpg",
      "modelo": [
        {"nombre":"clio", "color":"black"},
        {"nombre":"sandero", "color":"red"}
        ],
      "tab": "aveo"
    },
  ];


  }])
```

This expample here http://plnkr.co/edit/JmhcU06dypoCwOzszLom?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to use a filter:

```
 <ul ng-repeat="marca in marcas | filter:'chevrolet'">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

You can make another model in your `$scope` and use it to filter the `marcas` selected

1. `app.js` - add the following line

   `$scope.selectedModel = "Chevrolet";`
2. Change the `ng-repeat` in `index.html` to

   `<ul ng-repeat="marca in marcas | filter: selectedModel">`

This way you can use the new model `$scope.selectedModel` by setting it through some user input if you want. It won't be hard coded in the view.